# A simple way to extract information from this dataset with Query?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, query

I have a dataset comparable to the following (you may wrap it in `Dataset` if you like). I am looking for a relatively simple way to query it and extract information.

#### Sample dataset

```
ranStr[] := StringJoin@RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 5]

SeedRandom[321]
asc = 
  AssociationThread[
   CharacterRange["a", "e"],
   Table[
    Association@Table[
     With[{n = RandomInteger[{10, 20}]},
       ranStr[] -> <|
         "x" -> RandomInteger[10, n], 
         "y" -> RandomInteger[10, n], 
         "c" -> RandomInteger[7], 
         "d" -> RandomWord[]
       |>
      ],
      {RandomInteger[3, 6]}
     ],
     {5}
   ]
  ];
```

#### Description of the dataset structure

Let me describe it. First, we have two nested levels of associations, but this is included just to mimic an obstacle in the real data I have. What is important is the 3rd, innermost level, which contains the actual data in the keys `"x"`, `"y"`, `"c"`, `"d"`.

At the innermost level, `"x"` and `"y"` are a pair of vectors of exactly the same length. The $i$th element of `"x"` goes with the $i$th element of `"y"`, so it might have been better to store them like this:

```
asc // Query[1, 1, {"x", "y"} /* Transpose]

(* {<|"x" -> 10, "y" -> 10|>, <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 9|>, <|"x" -> 6, "y" -> 7|>, ... *)
```

But that is not how they are stored in this dataset.

`"c"` is a number which represents a threshold value.

`"d"` is just some arbitrary additional data to mimic the actual dataset I have better. In there real data, there are several such keys, so repeating their names in the `Query` just to retain them is very inconvenient.

#### The task

- Select those values of `"x"` where the corresponding value of `"y"` is greater than `"c"`.
- Ideally, retain `"c"` and `"d"` in the data.
- Ideally, use `Query` or `Dataset`.

#### Example output

Element `1,1` of the resulting dataset should look like the output of this:

```
xy = asc // Query[1, 1, {"x", "y"} /* Transpose];
c = asc // Query[1, 1, "c"];
d = asc // Query[1, 1, "d"];

<|"x" -> (xy // Query[Select[#y > c &], "x"]), "c" -> c, "d" -> d|>
(* <|"x" -> {10, 5, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2, 7, 10, 7}, "c" -> 5, "d" -> "bide"|> *)
```

Or like the output of this:

```
<|"xy" -> (xy // Query[Select[#y > c &]]), "c" -> c, "d" -> d|>
```

Or like the output of this:

```
<|"x" -> (xy // Query[Select[#y > c &], "x"]), 
  "y" -> (xy // Query[Select[#y > c &], "y"]), 
  "c" -> c, "d" -> d|>
```

**What I am looking for is a relatively simple and intuitive `Query` or combination of `Query`s that achieves this.**

The problems with doing something similar to how the example output is constructed above is:

- It involves splitting the dataset into parts, which would need to be `Merge`d back together. The two outer nested levels of associations make that inconvenient.
- Repeating the names of keys like `"d"` to retain them is very inconvenient.

---

The following would be a working but rather ugly solution that I am not happy with:

```
asc // 
 Query[All, All, <|#, "xy" -> KeyTake[{"x", "y"}][#]|> & /* KeyDrop[{"x", "y"}]] (* bundle x and y together *) //
 Query[All, All, {"xy" -> Transpose}] (* rearrange xy *) //
 Query[All, All, <|#, With[{c = #c}, "xy" -> Select[#xy, #x > c &]]|> &] (* filter with a threshold of x *) //
 Query[1, 1] (* remove this to see the whole output *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way that produces output that conforms to the first option:

```
val = asc //
  Query[
    All
  , All
  , <| "x" -> Pick[#x, Positive[#y-#c]], KeyDrop[#, {"x", "y"}] |> &
  ];

val[[1, 1]]

(* <|"x" -> {10, 5, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2, 7, 10, 7}, "c" -> 5, "d" -> "bide"|> *)
```